# NetworkOnMainThreadException when I change HTTP to HTTPS in AsyncTask or Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am stuck at this problem. The user inputs their website. It is either http or https, but when they input a https website I get a NetworkOnMainThreadExecption below is my AsyncTask. What am I doing wrong? If I remove the runOnUiThread I get a **Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views** error which I think means that any updated to the UI need to be done in a Thread? So when I put the updates in the Thread I get **NetworkOnMainThreadExecption** error.

```
private class runBabyRun extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {


    final TextView temperature = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTemp4);
    // a few more TextViews here

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            if (httpSelection.equals("http://")) {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                // get url data
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(weburi);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                webs = entity.getContent();
            }
            if (httpSelection.equals("https://")) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Entered https if statement ");
                HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
                SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
                socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
                registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
                SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());

                // Set verifier
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
                // get url data
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(weburi);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                webs = entity.getContent();
            }
            // convert response to string
            try {
                final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"),
                        8);
                // read one line of code, file is one whole string.
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            //split file into array using space as delimiter
                            String clientraw = reader.readLine();
                            String[] parts = clientraw.split(" ");
                               clientRawData.addAll(Arrays.asList(parts));
                            //A few more setting up of fields here
                            // Get Weather Station Title
                            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name(parts[32]));

                            temperature.setText(parts[4] + degrees);

                            time.setText(parts[29] + ":" + parts[30]);
                            date.setText(parts[74]);

                            webs.close();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in displaying textview " + e.toString());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }



                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting string " + e.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in Connection, please check your URL - " + weburi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // setup intent for Settings
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Setting.class);
            // Launch the Settings Activity using the intent for result
            startActivityForResult(intent, UPDATE_WEBURL);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS BELOW**
I have updated my app t have the onPostExecute and it looks like code below but I still get the NetworkOnMainThreadExeption error:
 **E/log_tag﹕ Error in displaying textview android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        // convert response to string
        try {
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"),
                    8);
            // read one line of code, file is one whole string.
            try {
                //split file into array using space as delimiter
                String clientraw = reader.readLine();
                String[] parts = clientraw.split(" ");

                // Get Weather Station Title
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name(parts[32]));
                temperature.setText(parts[4] + degrees);
                //and various other setTexts
                windDirection.setText(convertDegrees(parts[3]) + " " + "(" + (parts[3]) + "\u00b0" + ")");
                time.setText(parts[29] + ":" + parts[30]);
                date.setText(parts[74]);

                webs.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in displaying textview " + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting string " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

The error log I get is:

```
03-13 01:39:18.984    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish E/log_tag﹕ Error in displaying textview android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-13 01:39:18.984    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-13 01:39:18.984    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
03-13 01:39:18.984    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:657)
03-13 01:39:18.984    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
03-13 01:39:18.984    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:134)
03-13 01:39:18.984    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:174)
03-13 01:39:18.984    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:159)
03-13 01:39:18.984    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:231)
03-13 01:39:18.984    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:145)
03-13 01:39:18.984    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:397)
03-13 01:39:18.984    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish.MainActivity$runBabyRun.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:307)
03-13 01:39:18.984    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish.MainActivity$runBabyRun.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:227)
03-13 01:39:18.984    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
03-13 01:39:18.997    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-13 01:39:18.997    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
03-13 01:39:18.997    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-13 01:39:18.997    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-13 01:39:18.997    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-13 01:39:18.997    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-13 01:39:18.997    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-13 01:39:18.997    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-13 01:39:18.997    5299-5299/uk.co.diong.weatherlive_ish W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: It is time you post the relevant lines from the logcat. It tells you also which statement causes the exception.

Comment: You should remove the BufferedReader from onPostExecute. And hence the readLine(). Do that in doInBackground. Also the webs.close is network code which does not belong in onPostExecute.

Comment: I seem to be having problems with the **String clientraw = reader.readLine();**  So do I put webs.close and BufferReader in the doInBackgroud() and the **String clientraw = reader.readLine();** ?

Comment: I moved all **BufferReader** and **readLine()** and **webs.close()** to doInBackground and it works. I'm so happy. One whole day wasted but glad I resolved it and most important I learnt from this.

Comment: All should go to doInBackGround. That all is network code so that's why.

Comment: `glad I resolved it `. Be glad and realize your self that others solved it for you.

Comment: Yes that _is_ what I meant in a retrospective kind of way, "them magical peoples on stackoverflow, thems help me fixes it" ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is causing the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is the following line

```
 String clientraw = reader.readLine();
```

reading from a Stream obtained from a http call, is still a blocking operation and it has to be performed on a background thread

Comment: See, orb, why I don't like `runOnUiThread` in `AsyncTask`. It just complicates things when there's already methods for that.

Comment: orb you are right... I don't like AsyncTask either, but as I said, if one knows what is doing those kind of things rarely happen, @codeMagic

Comment: @codeMagic can you show me or point me to these methods that already do that? I am new to Android and Java for that matter should I do it in the **onPostExecute(Result)** method?

Comment: @Dino all methods **except** `doInBackground()`. So, if you are updating before the task is done (ex. update a `ProgressBar`) you could use `onPreExecute()` if you want to update UI after task finishes then you would use `onPostExecute()`

Comment: I actually didn't know that. I shall move it to onPostExecute()

Comment: @Blackbelt but won't I get an error if the AsyncTask goes to the background to get the file and then the UI thread will want to update the UI and it won't have the details because it hasn't finished? I thought the AsyncTask ran separately to the UI thread?

Comment: onPostExecuted runs on the UI Thread and runs always after doInBackground returns

Comment: What about the **String clientraw = reader.readLine();** part?

Comment: that goes in doInBackground. the reader object is reading from the network

Comment: It is still giving me the same error, I will update my question to show you want I have changed.

Comment: *String clientraw = reader.readLine();* goes in `doInBackground`